# Taylor series convergence for sin x

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

**a.** $\forall x\in(0,\pi/2),\quad x-\frac{x^3}{3!}<\sin x<x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!},$

**b.** $\forall x\in(0,\pi/2),\quad x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots-\frac{x^{4k-1}}{(4k-1)!}<\sin x<x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots+\frac{x^{4k+1}}{(4k+1)!},$

**c.** $\forall x\in(0,\pi/2),\quad x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots = \sin x.$

Hello!

I have been trying to prove these, but only had luck with the first two. I do get that you have to use part b. to solve c., but I have no idea how to connect them.

Comment: You can prove $c$ using the definition of the Taylor series: $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{f^{[n]}(a)}{a!}(x-a)^n$.

Comment: I did, but I have to use a and b to do the same thing. I am guessing the proof has to be about the fact that x^(4k+1)/(4k+1)! goes to 0 at big k's (or does it?), but I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: related http://math.stackexchange.com/a/745375/166923

Comment: (b) and (c) are connected because of the Sandwich Theorem I think... in the inequality in (b), take the limit as $k \rightarrow \infty$, then the leftmost and rightmost series become the same series in (c). Hence $\sin x$ is sandwiched by two limits that are the same and so we are done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a) and by the Maclaurin formula for the sine function there's $\theta\in(0,1)$ such that

$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\sin^{(4)}(\theta x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\sin(\theta x)>x-\frac{x^3}{3!},\; \forall x\in(0,\frac\pi2)$$
and

$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}\sin^{(6)}(\theta x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}\sin(\theta x)\\<x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!},\; \forall x\in(0,\frac\pi2)$$
so we deduce the result. Can you generalize this to find b)?

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$, $\sin''(x)=-\sin(x)$, $\sin^{[3]}(x)=-\cos(x)$ etc. Notice that the derivatives are periodic, alternating between $\sin$ & $\cos$ & changing sign every $2^{nd}$ term.

So in general, $\sin^{[n]}(x)=\begin{cases}\sin(x), & n=0+4k\\
\cos(x), & n=1+4k\\
-\sin(x), & n=2+4k\\
-\cos(x), & n=3+4k\\
\end{cases}\quad$
for integer $k$.

If we center the series at $a=0$, we have $\sin^{[n]}(0)=\begin{cases}0, & n\text{ is even}\\
1, & n=1+4k\\
-1, & n=3+4k\\
\end{cases}$

Sub. this into the definition for the Taylor series & get odd terms with coefficients of $\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}$. This should look familiar to $c$. Hope I helped.